# Swift Container View with UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I have a container view displaying a `UIPageViewController`. Everything is working ok, the only problem is the dots that display the pages. They are not able to adjust with the changing screen sizes.

```
pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY - 525,width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height: 50))
```

This is the piece of code I am using to change where the dots are displayed mainly the `UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY - 525` part. I am just checking on how I can have them adapt to the different screen sizes. Screen shots below of the problem. This first orange screen is correct on where I want the dots to be and the second one is wrong.

[image]

[image]

**More Code**

```
 func configurePageControl() {
    // The total number of pages that are available is based on how many available colors we have.
    pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY - 525,width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height: 50))
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = orderedViewControllers.count
    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
    self.pageControl.tintColor = UIColor.black
    self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
    self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
    self.view.addSubview(pageControl)
}
```

**How I am calling the views**

```
lazy var orderedViewControllers: [UIViewController] = {
    return [self.newVc(viewController: "sbBlue"),
            self.newVc(viewController: "sbRed")]
}()
```

Comment: Look into constraints

Comment: its set up programmatically, I add more code

Comment: Do you have a reference to the view that you want the PageControl to adjust to? (i.e. the orange or green views)

Comment: @LukasBimba, Do you want to adjust vertical position same for any screen size, Right ?

Comment: I am calling the views by using a storyboard ID, maybe I just need to figure out another way to accomplish the look I am going for?

Comment: @PaulMarshal Yes, the problem is that it will shift up or down depending on the screen size

Comment: UIPageViewController includes its own page control. Why don't you use that?

Comment: I was thinking about using a UIView and setting it to "UIPageControl" and setting the dots in storyboard instead of programmatically? Do you think that would work? I used a tutorial for the question I am asking so I was going off of the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for your issue.

You can get `maxY` position of your green or orange view and change your code like as follow. It will set your pageControl's vertical position by removing 30 pixel from bottom of your green or orange view.

```
pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: yourOrangeView.bounds.maxY - 30, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50))
```

Or

```
pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: yourGreenView.bounds.maxY - 30, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50))
```

I hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: I don't have my "red" and "orange" views as IBOutlets in the view controller with the container view. Should I try adding them? I am calling the views by "Storyboard ID", I will add the code...

Comment: Then, You can take outlet for same. It will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here.

- You should not be creating your own UIPageControl. UIPageViewController *has* a UIPageControl already; you should just use it.
- If you insist on supplying your own (unnecessary) UIPageControl, you need to position it with auto layout so that it takes account of size changes. This code is wrong:

  ```
  pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY - 525,width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height: 50))
  ```

  Don't give the page control a frame; give it auto layout constraints.